# Use value of labels in array inside array and create forEach

Tags: swift, list, foreach, swiftui

I have a JSON of a similar plan

```
[
{
    "id": "registration",
    "title": "auto",
    "info": "under update",
    "brand": "TESLA",
    "model": "MODEL X",
    "make_year": 2017,
    "properties": [
        {
                "id": 1,
                "icon": "ic_rgb",
                "label": "color",
                "value": "red"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "icon": "ic_car",
                "label": "tipe",
                "value": "car"
            },
            {   "id": 3,
                "icon": "ic_fuel",
                "label": "fuel",
                "value": "-"
            },

            ...

        ],
    },
{
    "id": "firstRegistration",
    "title": "auto",
    "info": "under update",
    "brand": "TESLA",
    "model": "MODEL X",
    "make_year": 2017
},
{
    "id": "secondRegistration",
    "title": "auto",
    "info": "under update",
    "brand": "TESLA",
    "model": "MODEL X",
    "make_year": 2017,
}
]
```

And my model is:

```
...
    struct Unicards: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String?
    var info: String?
    var brand: String?
    var model: String?
    var make_year: Int?
    var messege: String?
    var messege_color: String?
    var price: String?
    var price_currency: String?
    var price_tooltip: String?


    var properties: [HPropert]?
    struct HPropert: Hashable, Codable, Identifiable {

        var id: Int
        var icon: String?
        var label: String?
        var value: String?

    }
    }
```

Here is what I am doing http://joxi.ru/Q2KLXvYHLDz9aA

I use ScrollView(Axis.Set.horizontal) and forEach element 
but cannot loop element by data.properties.count

I am already pars JSON but can't loop element by count.

Can you please help me with an example?

How can i tryed

---

var data2: Unicards.HPropert

```
        HStack {

            ForEach(data2) { item in <--\\Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred
                VStack {

                                Image(image)
                                    .resizable()
                                    .scaledToFit()
                                    .frame(width: 34, height: 34)


                                VStack {

                                    Text(self.data2.label ?? "")
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                        .fontWeight(.medium)
                                    Text(self.data2.value ?? "")
                                        .font(.system(size: 14))
                                }


                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: Please add code that you are using to loop elements

Comment: updated post. Thx for attantion

Comment: Identifiable means that the compiler expects every object to have a unique id. All of your objects in the JSON have the same id.

Comment: Thnx all my object now have unique Id, i'm updating post, can you look, please?

`Generic parameter 'Data' could not be inferred`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

resolved

1st step is

```
var data2: Unicards  (your main data)
```

step 2 
new constant inside your body

```
 var body: some View {
let arrayWhatYouNeed = data2.propertie
```

and don't forget to return you view

```
return  HStack {
...
```

and now you have for example

return HStack {

```
        ForEach(arrayWhatYouNeed) { item in 
            VStack {

                            Image(image)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 34, height: 34)


                            VStack {

                                Text(item.lable)
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                                Text(item.value)
                                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                            }


            }
        }
}
```